# Flask: Button To Download Reactive Table From Query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am currently trying to figure out a table that is generated via query which uses reactive user input values, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make this happen. I've found similar questions, but no solutions have worked for me. I need help!

Here are the questions I've reviewed but can't seem to make anything work:

- [Flask button to save table from query as csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766499/flask-button-to-save-table-from-query-as-csv)
- [Return a response with an download option on the same HTML page using flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592863/return-a-response-with-an-download-option-on-the-same-html-page-using-flask)'
- [Create and download a CSV file from a Flask view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011341/create-and-download-a-csv-file-from-a-flask-view)

(This is all just example code as I can't post my actual code)

So, the route for the page showing the data is:

`routes.py`

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request, jsonify, send_file, make_response
from app import app
from app.forms import MyDataForm, MyDataTable
from app.models import MyData

@app.route('/my_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_data():
   myData = MyData.query.all()
   form = MyDataForm()
   table = MyData(myData)

   if request.method == 'GET':
      return render_template('my_data.html', title = 'My Data Table', form = form, myData = myData)

   elif request.method == 'POST':  
      selected = request.form.get('my_data_type')
      print(selected)
      table.col1.show = table.col2.show = table.col3.show = False

      if int(selected) == 1:
         myData = MyData.query.with_entities(MyData.col1, MyData.col2, MyData.col3)
         table = MyTable(myData)
         table.col1.show = True

      elif int(selected) == 2:
         myData = MyData.query.with_entities(MyData.col1, MyData.col2)
         table = MyTable(myData)
         table.col1.show = True

      else:
         myData = MyData.query.with_entities(MyData.col2, MyData.col3)
         table = MyTable(myData)
         table.col2.show = True

   if form.validate_on_submit() and request.form['form_name'] == 'Metric':

   return redirect(url_for('my_data'))
```

My forms file:

`forms.py`

```
from flask_table import Table, Col

class MyDataForm(FlaskForm):
   my_data_type = SelectField('Metric', choices = [(1, "Option 1"), (2, "Option 2"), (3, "Option 3")], default = 1)
   submit = SubmitField('Select Metric')

class MyTable(Table):
   classes = ['table', 'table-condensed']
   col1 = Col('Col1', show = False)
   col2 = Col('Col2', show = False)
   col3 = Col('Col3', show = False)
```

And then my html template for the page with the table:

`my_data.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block app_content %}
<div class = "container">
   <form action = "" method = "post">
      <fieldset>
         <legend>Select a metric:</legend>
         <div class ="form-group required">
            {{ form.my_data_type.label(class="form-control-label") }}
            {{ form.my_data_type(class="form-control") }}
         </div>
         <div class = "form-group">
            {{ form.submit(class="form-control") }}
         </div>
      </fieldset>
   </form>

   <!-- VVVV How can I link the returned data query to this download link?! VVV-->
   <a href="/return_table/" target="blank"><button class='btn btn-default'>Download Table!</button></a>
   <h3>My Data:</h3>
      {{ table }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If you've downvoted this, please leave a comment as to why so I can improve my question. Thank you

Comment: you have a pretty detailed question but I'm not sure what you've tried, if there are errors you're getting or if there is a topic you don't have a method to approach. would you mind trying to emphasize the front end expected result (ie what the user would do), how the back end should respond, and what you've tried including the issue you're experiencing?